# How would I clear an entire array?

Tags: java, arrays, save, load

I have to create a clear button that when pressed, clears all images off the screen. The images are currently in an array. I just saved what was in the array to the save.txt file. Now I need to click load, which clears all the image off the screen before loading where they previously were. How would I do this? This is my save code

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){

        if (arraysticker[image] != null){
            String name;
            int x,y;
            name = sticker.getname();
            x = sticker.getx();
            y = sticker.gety();
            fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
        }
    }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
    System.out.println("saved");
}
```

My entire code is

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EZ.initialize(1644,1022);//sets page size
    sticker [] arraysticker = new sticker [20];//creates an array to hold 20 sticker
    EZImage backgroundPicture = EZ.addImage("background.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight() / 2); //set position of background
    EZImage rectanglePicture = EZ.addImage("rectangle.png", EZ.getWindowWidth() / 2, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 7); //set position of palette
    EZImage hatPicture = EZ.addImage("hat.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 10, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6); //set position of stickers
    EZImage bluntPicture = EZ.addImage("blunt.png",1* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 3, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6); //set position of stickers
    EZImage dealwithitPicture = EZ.addImage("dealwithit.png",3* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 5, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6); //set position of stickers
    EZImage weedPicture = EZ.addImage("weed.png",10* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 11, EZ.getWindowHeight () / 6); //set position of stickers
    EZImage savePicture = EZ.addImage("save.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 3* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);  //set position of save button
    EZImage loadPicture = EZ.addImage("load.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 4* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);
    EZImage clearPicture = EZ.addImage("clear.png", 19* EZ.getWindowWidth() / 20, 5* EZ.getWindowHeight () / 9);

    EZSound hatsound = EZ.addSound("airhorn.wav"); //imports airhorn.wav and assigns it to hatsound
    EZSound bluntsound = EZ.addSound("yungdog.wav"); //import yungdog.wav and assigns it to bluntsound
    EZSound dealwithitsound = EZ.addSound("sandstorm.wav"); //imports sandstorm.wav and assigns it to dealwithitsound
    EZSound weedsound = EZ.addSound("weed.wav"); //imports weed.wav and assigns it to weedsound

    sticker arrayhat = new sticker (20, "hat.png");
    sticker arrayblunt = new sticker (20, "blunt.png");
    sticker arraydealwithit = new sticker (20, "dealwithit.png");
    sticker arrayweed = new sticker (20, "weed.png");

    int image = 0;//declares an integer variable named image
    //creates a boolean variable and sets it to false
    boolean hatSoundPlay = false;
    boolean bluntSoundPlay = false;
    boolean dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
    boolean weedSoundPlay = false;
        while (true){//while it is true
        if (EZInteraction.wasMouseLeftButtonReleased()){//if left button is released
        int clickX = EZInteraction.getXMouse(); //get x coordinates
        int clickY = EZInteraction.getYMouse();//get y coordinates

            if (hatPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if hat is in the x and y coordinates
                bluntSoundPlay = false; //turn all sounds false
                weedSoundPlay = false; 
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false; 
                if (!hatSoundPlay) { //if hatsound not play
                    hatsound.play(); //hatsound will play
                    hatSoundPlay = true; //hat sound is now true    
                }
            }
            else if(bluntPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if blunt is in the x and y coordinates
                hatSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                weedSoundPlay = false;
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false;
                if (!bluntSoundPlay) {//if bluntsound not play
                    bluntsound.play(); //then bluntsound will play
                    bluntSoundPlay = true; //bluntSoundPLay is now assigned to true
                }
            }
            else if(dealwithitPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if dealwithit is in the x and y coordinates
                hatSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                bluntSoundPlay = false;
                weedSoundPlay = false;
                if (!dealwithitSoundPlay) {//if dealwithitsound not play
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //then dealwithitsound will pay
                    dealwithitSoundPlay = true; //dealwithitSoundPlay is assigned as true
                }
            }
            else if(weedPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){//if weed is in the x and y coordinates
                dealwithitSoundPlay = false;//turn all sounds false
                hatSoundPlay = false;
                bluntSoundPlay = false;
                if (!weedSoundPlay) {//if weedsound not play
                    weedsound.play(); //then weedsound will play
                    weedSoundPlay = true; //sets the varialbe weedSoundPlay to true
                } 
            }


            else if (backgroundPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) && !clearPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY) 
                    && !rectanglePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                if (hatSoundPlay){ //if hatSoundPlay is true
                    hatsound.play(); //and a hatsound will play
                    sticker sticker1 = new sticker();//creates a new sticker1
                    sticker1.arraysticker(hatPicture, "hat.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker1;//puts sticker 1 into the array
                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");


                } else if (bluntSoundPlay){ //else if bluntSound is true
                    bluntsound.play(); //and blunt sound will play
                    sticker sticker2 = new sticker();
                    sticker2.arraysticker(bluntPicture, "blunt.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker2;//puts sticker 2 into the array

                }else if (dealwithitSoundPlay){ //if dealwithitsound is true
                    dealwithitsound.play(); //dealwithitsound will play
                    sticker sticker3 = new sticker();
                    sticker3.arraysticker(dealwithitPicture, "dealwithit.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker3;//puts sticker 3 into the array

                }else if (weedSoundPlay){ //if weedsound is true
                    weedsound.play(); //weedsound will also play
                    sticker sticker4 = new sticker();
                    sticker4.arraysticker(weedPicture, "weed.png", clickX, clickY);//places sticker
                    image ++;//increments image by 1
                    arraysticker[image] = sticker4;//puts sticker 4 into the array
                }
            }
            else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ 
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("save.txt");
                for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){

                    if (arraysticker[image] != null){
                        String name;
                        int x,y;
                        name = sticker.getname();
                        x = sticker.getx();
                        y = sticker.gety();
                        fw.write(name + " " + x + " " + y + "\n");
                    }
                }

                fw.flush();
                fw.close();
                System.out.println("saved");
            }
            /*else if (loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){
                Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File ("save.txt"));
                for (int i = 0; i < image; i++){
                    arraysticker.removeImage(arraysticker.image1[image]);
                }
            }*/

    }
        EZ.refreshScreen();     
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could `arraysticker = new sticker[arraysticker.length];` be enough?

Answer (score 2):

If arraysticker is not final then a simple reassignment would work:

```
arraysticker = new sicker[arraysticker.length];
```

This assumes you need the array to remain the same size. If that's not necessary then create an empty array:

```
arraysticker = new sicker[0];
```

If it is final then you could null out all the elements:

```
Arrays.fill( arraysticker, null );
```

Comment: I also want it cleared off the screen. all the images previously placed, i want it all gone. because when i click the load button, it has to wipe the entire run screen clean and load what ever i saved.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign `null` to the reference.

```
arraysticker = null; // garbage collector will take care
```

or

```
arraysticker = new sicker[arraysticker.length]; // initialized to new length
```

or use

[Arrays.fill(arraysticker, null);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29)

> it just loops through every element and sets it to null. This of
>   course doesn't allow you to resize the array (to zero), if that's what
>   you meant by "empty".

```
public static void fill(Object[] a,Object val)
```

> Assigns the specified Object reference to each element of the
>   specified array of Objects.
>
> Parameters:
>       a - the array to be filled
>       val - the value to be stored in all elements of the array Throws:
>       ArrayStoreException - if the specified value is not of a runtime type that can be stored in the specified array